# Is there a tool to check Python distribution (sdist) files?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, sdist

We've had the case where we released a Python source distribution (sdist) file on PyPI, and there was an issue that was only noticed after making the release. Namely for some files, the permissions were set to not allow read by all, and then in some cases those files couldn't be read on user machines after they installed the package with `sudo`.

We're considering starting our own script to check an sdist for this issue and to run it before uploading to PyPI.

Is there a tool (or something in setuptools or twine or somewhere) to run this or other basic checks on an sdist before uploading it available already?